# Map marker are not in the map on IE

Tags: javascript, google-maps, internet-explorer, google-maps-api-3

This is my code..

```
var styles = [
  {
    "featureType": "landscape",
    "stylers": [
      {"weight": 0.1},
      {"color": "#E7EDEF"}
    ]
  },
  ...
  {
    "featureType": "poi.park",
    "elementType": "labels",
    "stylers": [
      {"visibility": "on"}
    ]
  }
];

var map;
function initialize() {
  var centerM = new google.maps.LatLng(42.641185, 14.015790);
  var iconBase = window.location.origin + Drupal.settings.basePath + 'sites/default/themes/actomedia/img/';

  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 15,
    center: centerM,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    styles: styles,
    scrollwheel: false
  };        

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  // Map Marker & infoBox
  markerOpt = {
    map: map,
    icon: iconBase + 'puntoEnergy_map_ico.png',
    title: 'Punto Energy',
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
  };
   markerPicasso = new google.maps.Marker($.extend({position: centerM}, markerOpt));

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

And the map works fine in Chrome and Firefox but in IE the marker is not showed.
Someone know how to fix that?

I tryed to remove the marker animation, check all the commas in the code but it still don't work T_T

--- UPDATE! ---

Following Anto Jurković question I tryed to print the icon URL and I find there is a bug in the window.location.origin who return undefined to me.

I fixed it putting this code on the top of the js file (surce)[1](http://tosbourn.com/a-fix-for-window-location-origin-in-internet-explorer/)

```
if (!window.location.origin) {
  window.location.origin = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + (window.location.port ? ':' + window.location.port: '');
}
```

Comment: Now I'm debugging IE10 but after that I have to check 9th and 8th too ^^

Comment: I checked this code with IE10, 9 and 8 and there were no problems. The only difference was icon. And most probably styling of div map-canvas, html and body.

Comment: Do you see your icon in IE if you load it as a file?

Answer (score 0):

I am Creting Marker Using below function :

```
createMarker(Map, legs[i].start_location, legs[i].start_address, markerletter);

function createMarker(map, latlng, html, color) {       
    var contentString = html;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map,
        shadow: iconShadow,
        icon: getMarkerImage(color),
        shape: iconShape,           
        zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat() * -100000) << 5
    });

    //marker.myname = label;
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        //Set Infowindow Logic
    });
    return marker;
}
```

> Javascript

```
function initialize() {
    var Lattts = document.getElementById('lat').value;
    var Longgs = document.getElementById('long').value;    

    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(Lattts), parseFloat(Longgs));
    var map_canvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
    var map_options = {
        center: myLatlng,
        zoom: 17,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options)

    var icon = {            
        url: 'https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/blue-dot.png'
    };

    var contentString = 'Contents';

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        icon: icon,
        zIndex: Math.round(myLatlng.lat() * -100000) << 5,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
    });

    //marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
        if (marker.getAnimation() != null) {
            marker.setAnimation(null);
        } else {
            marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
        }
    });

        setTimeout(function () { marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE); }, 2000);
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```